# Using LibvlcSharp, how can I change the speed that a video is playing

Tags: c#, winforms, libvlcsharp

I am using Libvlcscharp V3.5 in a windows forms application in visual studio 2019
I am playing a video stored on my hard drive.
Is it possible to change the speed that the video is playing.
I found the MediaPlayer.Rate but it only gets the rate which is set to 1
Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Use mediaPlayer.SetRate(). It is not a setter so you can check the return value in case of error : https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp/blob/08d69ff861a4f93431c02452028d0d663c54a6f1/src/LibVLCSharp/Shared/MediaPlayer.cs#L863

Comment: Feel free to mark this as an answer then 